# VBA - no se encuentra control en frame o multipage

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy lanzando un calendario desde un `commandbutton` y pasando la fecha seleccionada a un `textbox`. Se hace sin problema cuando están ambos controles en el cuerpo del formulario.

El problema surge cuando los controles están dentro de un `frame` o `multipage` dentro de `frame`.

Probé recorriendo los controles del `frame` y también me da el error.

---

```
Function EnviarFecha(NumeroDia As Integer)


    For Each UserForm In UserForms
    
        If UserForm.Name = Formulario Then
            UserForm.Show
           
                UserForm.Controls(ControlFecha).Value = Format(NumeroDia & "/" & Cbx_mes.Value & "/" & Cbx_Anio.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
          
        End If
    Next UserForm
    Me.Hide
    
End Function
```

El error que me da es objeto no encontrado. Aquí una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien aqui esta el archivo fuente, para que puedan verlo detalladamente, es un calendario emergente y muy util.

[Calendario](https://download1081.mediafire.com/birn3z5fd0vg/qlfr18lln1orwwu/Calendario.xlsb)

Comment: Qué error te da? Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: Si tu código transcrito en tu pregunta exacto al que ejecutas, entonces: ``UserForm.Name = Formulario `` como Name es un string y Formulario no está entrecomillado va a tratar de buscar un objeto Formulario que tal vez sea una variable pero no se deduce de tu código ni esta como parametro y si no encuentra 
error salta a la vista . Igual revisa el caso para ``ControlFecha``. En todo caso pon más informacion

Comment: Ya agregue el archivo de Excel con el que estoy trabajando para que lo puedas ver. En form2 hay controles dentro de un frame que es donde aparece el error.